# Filter in a Pivot Table - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am unable to filter a Pivot Table in Excel. I've tried to use use the True and False method, but without success because it generates the following error "Unable to get the property of PivotField PivotItems class" (err.number = 1004). after I tried to use a For Each. For each with that I managed to change the filters, since I do not alter the first item on my PivotTable.

Method True - False

```
Sub TandF()
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica2").ClearAllFilters
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica2").PivotFields("Mês")
        .PivotItems("01/01/2015").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("02/01/2015").Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Method For each

```
Function filter(dtIni As String, dtFim As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo e
    Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
    Dim pvtItm As PivotItem
    dtIni = Format(dtIni, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    dtFim = Format(dtFim, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    Set PvtTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica2")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica2").ClearAllFilters

    For Each pvtItm In PvtTbl.PivotFields("Mês").PivotItems
        If (pvtItm <> dtIni) And (pvtItm <> dtFim) Then
            pvtItm.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
    filter = True
    Exit Function
e:
    MsgBox "Erro: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Erro ao Adicionar Filtros"
    filter = False

End Function
```

Comment: I had to do this once, I am not sure exactly the answer. But i know I found the answer the old "cheat way". Hit record macro do what you want to do. Then stop recording and following the code/logic it gives you.